Use Azure DevOps Library to update variables in .json file using FileTransform@2
I'm trying to update my json file using FileTransform@2 by using variables from the Azure DevOps Library to populate these, but I am just getting an error that the value is already there.

##[error]Failed to apply JSON variable substitution. Changes are already present in the package.

This is part of my YAML file:
stages:
  - stage: UpdateSettingsFile
    displayName: 'Update settings file with ADO values'
    jobs:
      - job: UpdateSettings
        steps:
          - task: FileTransform@2
            displayName: 'Transform JSON Configuration'
            inputs:
              folderPath: '**/'
              fileType: 'json'
              jsonTargetFiles: '**/${{ parameters.powerPlatformEnvironment }}-deployment-settings.json'
              JSONVariableSubstitution: true 
              Overwrite: true  # Overwrite the existing file

and this is an example of my .json file
{
  "EnvironmentVariables": [
      {
          "SchemaName": "firstEmail",
          "Value": "$(firstEmail)"
      }
]
}

Should the value be left blank? How can i get around this?
The values should be updating in the .json file to import to Power Platform

The reason of the issue is that you defined the variable with wrong name. To use the FileTransform@2 task to perform variable substitution in JSON file, you must define the variable using JSONPath expressions. See my answer below for more details. @thmswlkr

You can use extension Replace Tokens, which can replace tokens in text based files with variable value. For example,
my.json:
{
  "EnvironmentVariables": [
      {
          "SchemaName": "firstEmail",
          "Value": "$(firstEmail)"
      }
]
}

YAML file:
variables:
- group: Test

steps:
  - task: replacetokens@6
    inputs:
      sources: 'my.json'
      tokenPattern: 'azpipelines'
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'cat my.json'

Variable Group:

Result:


Update:
If you can only use FileTransform@2 task,

Change your variable defined in variable group as Json format. See the details as mentioned by @Bright Ran-MSFT.  In your example, there is one object, so the variable name looks like below.


Format your FileTransform@2 task. When you want to replace tokens in JSON file, only folderPath and jsonTargetFiles are needed. This task doesn't have parameters fileType, JSONVariableSubstitution and Overwrite. See the details about this task from FileTransform@2 - File transform v2 task.



Hi, I'm unable to install the replaceTokens extension (or any others) from Marketplace. Do you have any other suggestions?

Hi @thmswlkr, if you can only use FileTransform@2 task, you need to change your variable defined in variable group as Json format. In your example, there is one object, so the variable name will be EnvironmentVariables.0.Value. Besides, you need to format your FileTransform@2 task, see my update above.

The reason of the issue is that you defined the variable with wrong name. To use the FileTransform@2 task to perform variable substitution in JSON file, you need to must define the variable using JSONPath expressions.
See below example as reference:

The sample of JSON file (config.json). And want to use the FileTransform@2 task to replace "init01@example.com" and "init02@example.com" with two new values.
// config.json

{
    "EnvironmentVariables": [
        {
            "SchemaName": "firstEmail",
            "Value": "init01@example.com"
        },
        {
            "SchemaName": "secondEmail",
            "Value": "init02@example.com"
        }
    ]
}



The sample of pipeline main YAML (azure-pipelines.yml).
# azure-pipelines.yml

# Define the pipeline variables with the new values to replace the old value in JSON file.
# The names of variables must use JSONPath expressions.
variables:
  EnvironmentVariables.0.Value: 'user01@example.com'
  EnvironmentVariables.1.Value: 'user02@example.com'

steps:
- bash: |
    cat config.json
  displayName: 'Print JSON before Variable substitution'

- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: 'Variable substitution for JSON'
  inputs:
    folderPath: ''
    xmlTransformationRules: ''
    jsonTargetFiles: 'config.json'

- bash: |
    cat config.json
  displayName: 'Print JSON after Variable substitution'


The result.



Related documentations:

FileTransform@2 - File transform v2 task
File and variable transform


